# slack huddle isn't showing all of the sudden

Tags: slack

I was using slack for a while now and slack huddle is extremely useful. But, few days back slack huddle isn't showing in the bottom and it completely disappeared.

Any fix to get it back ?

Comment: Can you confirm if it is disabled by your Slack Admins?

Comment: @SuyashGaur Nope it isn't

Comment: Did you clear Slack's Cache - Ctrl + Shift + R?

Comment: Nope, dint do anything @SuyashGaur

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem intermittently - that the Huddle button disappears. I've found that posting a message in the channel makes the button reappear.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).